# is there a relationship between $\ell (R/I^n)$ and $\ell (R/I)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay, local-rings

$(R,m)$ is local neotherian cohen-macaulay ring of dimension $d$, and $I$ is an $m$-primary ideal of $R$. since $I$ is an $m$-primary, $\dim R /I=\dim R/I^n =0$. so  $\ell(R/I^n)$ and $\ell (R/I)$ are finite.
  i saw in papers, when $d=1$, they say  $\ell (R/I^n)=n.\ell (R/I)$. but I dont know why. and I wonder if this can be generalized to arbitrary dimension? so the question is:

> is there a relationship between $\ell (R/I^n)$ and $\ell (R/I)$?

thank you

Comment: you can add assumptions if needed

Comment: Even for $d=1$, what you state is not correct. For example take $R=k[[t^2,t^3]]$ and $I$ the maximal ideal. Then $\ell(R/I)=1, \ell(R/I^2)=3$.